# WordPress Archive Links not working

Tags: wordpress

Was put on a project to fix the archive links on a WordPress site. It's someone else's code and is quite messy.

**Problem:** Archive widget displays fine in the side bar, but links themselves do not work. Clicking link (e.g. www.site.com/2015/03/) does not sort posts, page loads but only with most recent posts (url changes though).

**My Attempts:**

1. deleted .htaccess file
2. Saved permalinks again in settings
3. turned off all plugins
4. replaced all WP core files
5. changed themes - **NOTE:** Works with TwentyFifteen Theme

Based on what I've tried, the only thing that worked was changing themes. This isn't an option though. What can I do to help sift through the code, are there any tips for troubleshooting?

Thanks for the help!

**Edits**
There is no archive.php page. There is a custom blog.php page, here is the loop it's using.

```
 <?php 
                $temp = $wp_query; $wp_query= null;
    $wp_query = new WP_Query(); $wp_query->query('cat=' . get_cat_ID("Blog") . '&showposts=5' . '&paged='.$paged);
    while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
                    ?>
                    <div id="post-<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>" <?php echo post_class(); ?>>
                        <div class="eachPost">
                                <div class="postTitle"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="Title"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
                           <div class="postMeta">
                               by <?php the_author(); ?> on <?php the_time('F jS, Y'); ?>
                           </div>
                           <div class="entry">
                           <?php 
global $more;    // Declare global $more (before the loop).
$more = 0;       // Set (inside the loop) to display content above the more tag.
the_content('Read the rest of this entry &#10142;');
?>


                            </div><!-- entry -->
                        </div><!-- eachPost -->
                        <div class="postMetaComments">
                            <div class="postComments">
                                <?php comments_popup_link('No Comments ', '1 Comment ', '% Comments '); ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clear-both"></div>
                        </div>  <!-- postMetaComments -->
                    </div><!-- /#post-<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?> -->
    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Check your theme's index.php or archive.php (if it exists) to see if the query is hardcoded. There is not much that can be told without seeing any code.

Comment: Thanks @Kaloyan, the Archive is being included via the sidebar widget. This is how they have the posts being output, is that what you meant by checking to see if the query is hardcoded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following might be considered a first step in troubleshooting. You mentioned there is no archive.php file. If there is also no date.php file, copy the code you pasted in your question into a new file, within the theme folder, called date.php. Replace everything in the first <?php ?> tag with this:

```
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
```

From the comments in your question I assume you know to include the snippets before and after the loop again also. E.g.

```
get_header();

// Loop goes here

get_footer();
```

I once had a SEO plugin installed and checked the 'disable date-based archives'. I doubt this would be the problem in your scenario, seeing as changing to TwentyFifteen theme corrects the problem.

Comment: Thank you! That fixed things. I basically made a duplicate of my blog page, swapped in your first step and things are displaying fine.

Comment: Thank you for the tip on checking if Yoast SEO had been set to 'disable date-based archives'. Have fallen for that a few times ...

Comment: It was **Yoast's** date archives settings that got me too... it recommends you disable date archives and it even seems to be off by default. Definitely one to watch out for.